# JS, Browserify: function not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, module, browserify

I have files as represented:

```
-js/
    - calc.js
    - tool.js
-index.html
```

calc.js is a node module of following structure:

```
module.exports = {
   calculate: function() {...},
   getPrecision: function() {...}
}
```

and tool.js use `require` and adds some functions, like that:

```
const fpcalc = require('./fpcalc');

function changeState() {
//some code using fpcalc
}
```

I used Browserify to generate `bundle.js` and added that as script src. 
One of my buttons on HTML page is using `onclick=changeState()`. After clicking I'm getting

```
ReferenceError: changeState is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

Why is that? Is there any other way to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function "changeState" is not exported in your tool.js.
That means it is only visible inside your bundle.js, but not outside.

Have a look at this: https://makerlog.org/posts/creating-js-library-builds-with-browserify-and-other-npm-modules

It shows you how to expose your code to the global namespace in javascript.

Comment: The link is dead. Luckily I found a snapshot on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20210302064211/https://makerlog.org/posts/creating-js-library-builds-with-browserify-and-other-npm-modules

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very simple way to make it work like you want.

```
const fpcalc = require('./fpcalc');

window.changeState = () => {
    //some code using fpcalc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same error, here is my working example.

mac, browserify https://github.com/perliedman/reproject

1. Must use `sudo` install globally

   `sudo npm install -g brwoserify`

   https://github.com/perliedman/reproject

   `sudo npm install reproject    // install locally is fine`

   Must manually create 'dist' folder for later output file use
2. Must use `--s` expose global variable function '`reproject`' and or '`toWgs84`' you will use later in browser js.

   Without `--s` , will get '`reproject`' **undefined error** . https://makerlog.org/posts/creating-js-library-builds-with-browserify-and-other-npm-modules
   browserify `--help` will list all options.
   `-o` means output file directory

   `browserify node_modules/reproject/index.js --s reproject -o node_modules/reproject/dist/reproject.js`

HTML script tag include your above `dist/reproject.js`

Now, you will not get 'reproejct' undefined error

```
return reproject(_geometry_, ___from_projection, proj4.WGS84, crss)
```